# How to create alphabet array during compile time?

Tags: rust, metaprogramming

I have a function which is called quite frequently which needs the letters of the alphabet in a vector.

To do so during runtime es quite easy:

```rust
let alphabet = (b'a'..b'z').map(|c| c as char).map(|c| c.to_string());
// Do some stuff with the alphabet...
```

Ok one can create another function creating this alphabet and then applying memorization on top of it...

...but I have heard that rust has a powerful macro feature.

How to create this vector - or maybe better a fixed size array with items of type `str` - during compile-time?

In other words I do want to have something like this

```rust
const alphabet: [&'static str; 26] = ["a", "b", ...];
```

auto generated.

Or is it better not to concern about this kind of optimization because the compiler does this anyway?

Answer (score 4):

If the content, you want to generate at compile time, is complex and you are not comfortable hardcoding it by hand, then you could write a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#case-study-code-generation) for it. The build script would then generate the "hardcoded" rust code and write it into a file. Then you would [include](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html) the generated file from your usual code.